# Label for checkbox is grayed out even though the checkbox is Not disabled - how to fix this?

Tags: html, checkbox, label

**The Code:**

```html
 <input type='checkbox' id='chkDbFields'>
 <label for='chkDbFields'>Db Fields</label>
```

- The label will be grayed out even though the checkbox is not disabled.
- Clicking the check box checks and un-checks the checkbox as you would expect.
- Clicking the label checks and un-checks the checkbox like I want it to... but the text looks grayed out like it's disabled... although it's not!
- I did not set up any CSS for the label tag at all.
- This is running on Safari 14.0.2 on an iMac.

Any ideas why its doing this? And, how can I correct it.

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Why don't you use event listners on the text. Put like a click event listener, which will then check and uncheck the check box through js.

Comment: A `<label>` element doesn't gray out. Please provide all the relevant code.